# contentEditable and lastChild IE, Firefox & Chrome LastChild

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Apologies for the long question, but I've tried a lot of things and done some research and havent found much of a solution. I have a content editable div.

```
  <div contentEditable=true onkeyup='showResult(this.lastChild.textContent)'></div>
```

When a user types something into this div, the showResult javascript runs which is basically an ajax request which returns a list of items that match. When a user clicks on one of the suggestions, say the name "John", a span with the suggestion is added into this contentEditable div like so:

```
<div contentEditable=true onkeyup='showResult(this.lastChild.textContent)'>
  <span id='uniqueId1' class='SpanClass' contentEditable='false'>John</span>
</div>
```

Having selected one Name, the user may want to search for another name. It HTML terms, that means that they would be typing the following:

```
<div contentEditable=true onkeyup='showResult(this.lastChild.textContent)'>
  <span id='uniqueId1' class='SpanClass' contentEditable='false'>John</span>
New User Text Goes Here
</div>
```

On Chrome, the right behaviour happens when the user continues tries typing in the div - the showResult function runs on the new text that the user types in and ignores the span elements. For Example, if the user types in "Fr" having already selected John, it ignores the first children (John), and sends what the user typed off via ajax and returns suggestions like Fred and Frankie.

However, in IE the span is still content editable and the user can't add any text other than within the span, which seems to make no sense as it is clearly contentEditable=false The ajax request is therefore run on the "John" text plus whatever the user types in next, which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Finally, in Firefox, the span is not contentEditable BUT the lastChild bit only picks up text within the span, and ignores the text the user puts in.

I've console logged the results of showResult(this.lastChild.textContent) to see what is being sent to the ajax request.

**In Chrome, typing in "Fr" in the box after the "John" span sends "Fr" to the ajax and returns the right result.**

**In IE, typing in "Fr" in the box sends "JohnFr"**

**In Firefox, typing in "Fr" just sends "John".**

As the issue is with this lastChild and the span, I've also included the Javascript that creates the span element. This only activates after a successful result is return and the result is clicked on. (please excuse the very messy Javascript/Jquery)

```
$('body').on("click", '.TagHints', function(){
//Once you click on the suggestion
var ThisData = $(this).data("id");
var ThisId = $(this).attr("id");
var ThisTag = $(this).data("tag");

//delete the text that the user typed in
elementToRemove = document.getElementById("FakeInput").lastChild;
document.getElementById("FakeInput").removeChild(elementToRemove);

var TagDiv = document.createElement('span');
TagDiv.className = 'SpanClass';
TagDiv.id = ThisId;
TagDiv.innerHTML = ThisTag;
TagDiv.contentEditable=false;

//append the Span to the contentEditable div
document.getElementById("FakeInput").appendChild(TagDiv);

var TagHints = document.getElementsByClassName("TagHints");
    while(TagHints.length > 0){
    TagHints[0].parentNode.removeChild(TagHints[0]);
    }

});
```

Why are the three browsers behaving completely differently and how do I get them all to behave like Chrome is? **Is there a better way of getting the text not in the spans?**

I read on another answer that firefox likes inputs and IE likes breaks in this context but both do not seem to work for me. :-(.

One big stopper to good solutions is that jQuery stops working after about line 6, which has also completely baffled me. If anyone can explain why its not working, that would also be cool. Maybe something to do with it being an ajax query and content being created after jquery is loaded?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, although I haven't had any responses I've come up with a workaround. However, lastChild is still behaving differently between the three browsers so would appreciate any further input.

The answer was to have a function in the document ready section which cloned the original div, stripped it of its children and grabbed the text on key up using Jquery. This then passed the result to the showResult function like so:

```
 $('#FakeInput').keyup(function(){
 var ThisClone =  $('#FakeInput').clone()
     .children()
       .remove()
       .end()
       .text();
  showResult(ThisClone);

  });
```

Equally, rather than trying to remove the text that the user typed in from the divs when the user makes a selection I simply cloned the items in the span, using their class, then emptied the contents of the div and reappended these cloned divs.

```
var TagItems = $('.TagItems').clone();
$('#FakeInput').empty();
$('#FakeInput').append(TagItems);
```

This solution works across the three browsers.

Comment: I work on the IE team and was interested in this question so I worked up a fiddle to investigate further the three major approaches. You may find [the results](https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/546471628679294976) to be of interest. I didn't immediately see the spec stating which approach browsers *should* take, but it does appear as though IE and Chrome are converging.